# Get the id of the popover button

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I'm dynamically adding buttons to the DOM. On each button, there's a popover. Here's my code:-

```
<button class="pop-Add" id='button1'>Add</button>

var popOverSettings = {
placement: 'bottom',
container: 'body',
selector: '[rel="popover"]',
html:true,
content: "<button type='button' id='+50' class='btn btn-small pop_button'> + 50 </button>"
}

$('body').popover(popOverSettings);
$('.pop-Add').click(function () {
        var id = Math.floor((Math.random() * 1000000) + 1);
    button = "<button rel='popover' id='" + id + "'>Click me</button>"
    $('body').append(button);
});
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RRGnb/484/)

I want to get the id of that `ClickMe` button whose popover button '+50' is clicked. How can I get it?

This is how I'm currently doing:-

```
$(document).on('click', '.bid_value_buttons' , function(){
    alert($(this).attr('id'))
}
```

Comment: And what is the issue in this approach?

Comment: It gives me the id as `+50`. I rather want the `id` of `ClickMe` button that I generated using `Math.random`

Comment: Doesnt matter. Any guidance in this perspective?

Comment: is a single popover shared across multiple buttons, like in your fiddle?

Comment: Using a random number for an ID is not that great an idea. You will, eventually, end up with a duplicate which may result in random UI interaction issues which will be hard to track down.  It would be better to use a unique prefix + a counter that you increment for each element added.

Comment: @Rajesh - Yes. it is.

Comment: @Makyen - It's just a demo.

Comment: kindly see my answer Hope it will helps you.

Comment: @SunilKumar please don't advertise your answer in comments. He saw you answered.

Comment: @PythonEnthusiast Please delete nonconstructive comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have done this  by using below code:

**HTML:**

```
    <button class="pop-Add">Add</button>
<script>
 function display(el) {
        var id = $(el).parent().parent().prev().prop("id");
        alert(id);
    }
    </script>
```

**jQuery Code:**

```
var popOverSettings = {
    placement: 'bottom',
    container: 'body',
    selector: '[rel="popover"]',
    html:true,
    content: "<button type='button' id='+50' class='btn btn-small btn-empty bid_value_buttons'> + 50 </button>"
}

$('body').popover(popOverSettings);
$('.pop-Add').click(function () {
        var id = Math.floor((Math.random() * 1000000) + 1);
    button = "<button rel='popover' id='" + id + "' OnClick='display(this);'>Click me</button>"
    $('body').append(button);
});
```

checkout this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ecd9ofs0/).

Please find below the screenshot :

[image]

Hope it helps you

Thanks

Comment: Please re-read the question. He wants to alert the id of the button that was clicked when clicking the other button in the overlay

Comment: +1 It was too early for me to figure out the parent relationship. This will work if the html does not change.

Comment: yes this will work if parent and child relationship is same.. Thanks for +1 :)

Comment: This will not work in cases where you add multiple buttons and  then click on `click me`. Also you can rather use `.parents('.popover').prev()`

Comment: Please fix for multiple buttons

Comment: @Rajesh I think it's already working for multiple click me buttons. I have add screenshot in my answer.. Please have a look and let me know If I'm right. Thanks

Comment: It doesn't work if: **Step 1:** Add two buttons without clicking the +50. **Step 2.** Click both of the +50s. One of them  will return undefined.

Answer (score 2):

I think the most simple answer would be to just add the id of the "click me" button as a `data-attribute` to the newly created popover and accessing that `data-attribute`:

[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RRGnb/490/)

```
$(document).on('click', '.click-me-button', function(){
    var id = $(this).attr('id');
    $('.popover-content').last().attr('data-id', id); // Will always be the last popover (newest in DOM)
})

$(document).on('click', '.popover-content' , function(){
    alert($(this).attr('data-id'));
});
```

And if you really need to access the button based off the id, you could just do:

```
$(document).on('click', '.popover-content' , function(){
   var id = $(this).attr('data-id');    
   alert($('#' + id).attr('id')); // easily access the id
});
```

Comment: This will alert button2 when clicking button1 after adding two buttons